# Find array in array, in sequence

Tags: php, arrays

How to code up a `[find-array-in-array]` function?

*Psuedo-code*

**Haystack**:

```
array(0=a, 1=b, 2=a, 3=b, 4=c, 5=c, 6=a, 7=b, 8=d, 9=c, 10=a, 11=b, 12=a, 13=b, 14=c);
```

**Needle**:

```
array(a, b, c);
```

**Return**:

```
array ( array (2, 3, 4), array(12, 13, 14) )
```

**Desired**: 
The Keys from Haystack that match Needle. The above should give 2 matches:

1. match = Haystack 2-4
2. match = Haystack 12-14

It should not find `"a b"`, `"a b d"` nor `"c a b"` etc., 
only instances of each value in Needle - in the specified order.

I'd like to make it a function so I can run it repeatedly (I have lots of these patterns).

I've tried doing this with nested foreachs, and driven myself nuts with counters etc.
I get to a certain point, and am unable to separate matches from non-matches.
(Surprised there isn't a built in function?  `in_array` and `array_intersect` seem to be for individual values only, not collections?)

---

```
$haystack = array('a','b','a','b','c','d','a','b','c');
$needle = array('a','b','c');

$CountH = count($haystack); echo $CountH."<br/>";
$CountN = count($needle); echo $CountN."<br/>";
$matches ='';
foreach ($haystack as $key1=>$haystackval){
    foreach ($needle as $key2=>$needleval) {
        $fail = '0';
        //if (in_array($needleval, $haystack)) {
        if ($key2[$needleval] === $haystackval && $fail === '0') {
            echo "Got needleval - ".$needleval ."<br/>";
        } 
        else { $fail='1';
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is each element of the haystack a single character?

Comment: This is a little too specific to be a built in function. Can you show us some code you've tried to write yourself? Otherwise this is just a case of you asking for code, which isn't really what SO is for

Comment: ah, a beautiful example of a finite state automata.

Comment: @Pudge601 - I'll update for you.

Comment: @Jack - No, it may range from single chars to 20 chars ... thus you could see "a bbbbbbbbb ccccc dddddddddddddddddddd"

Comment: @Pudge601 - what makes you say this is too specific?  There are numerous suggestions/routes to find individual values in php (in array, flipping to use keys, using intersect etc. .... but not a single method for looking for multiple values in order ... which though not common, I would have thought occurs every so often?

Comment: @theclueless1, You may be right, it might not be too specific a task, I guess it's just finding a sequence within an array.. just felt kind of scenario specific when I first saw it :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My attempt at creating this function;

```
function find_array_in_array($needle, $haystack) {
    $keys = array_keys($haystack, $needle[0]);
    $out = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $add = true;
        $result = array();
        foreach ($needle as $i => $value) {
            if (!(isset($haystack[$key + $i]) && $haystack[$key + $i] == $value)) {
                $add = false;
                break;
            }
            $result[] = $key + $i;
        }
        if ($add == true) { 
            $out[] = $result;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}

$haystack = array('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c');

$needle = array('a', 'b', 'c');

print_r(find_array_in_array($needle, $haystack));
```

Outputs;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 14
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you - that appears to work ... and I think I can follow the logic# (The code looks simple - yet for the life of me, I couldn't figure breaks etc. - again, thank you!)

Comment: No problem =] Jack's answer is, admittedly, quite satisfyingly concise compared to mine, but the advantage of this one is that the array values can be of any type, such as an object etc.

Comment: Well - I'm not 100% sure, but I think Jacks is ever so slightly faster ... but both are great - thank you both Pudge601 & Jack

Comment: Selected as answer due to flexibility

Comment: @Pudge601 you are genius!

Answer (score 3):

If the haystack consists of letters, you can do this in the string domain:

```
$haystack = array('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c');
$haystack = join('', $haystack);

preg_match_all('/abc/', $haystack, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

print_r(array_map(function($item) {
  return range($item[1], $item[1] + strlen($item[0]) - 1);
}, $matches[0]));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 14
        )

)
```

With potentially multiple characters inside the haystack, you need to resort to this:

```
$haystack = array('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c');
$needle = array('a', 'b', 'c');

// cache array sizes
$haystack_len = count($haystack);
$needle_len = count($needle);

// shortlist the possible starting keys
$possible_keys = array_keys($haystack, $needle[0], true);

$results = array();

foreach ($possible_keys as $index) {
    // start searching
    $i = $index; $j = 0;
    while ($i < $haystack_len && $j < $needle_len) {
        if ($haystack[$i] !== $needle[$j]) {
            continue 2; // no match
        }
        ++$i; ++$j;
    }
    // match
    $results[] = range($index, $index + $needle_len - 1);
}

print_r($results);
```

Comment: this works, but i really hope for a more flexible solution, one where the haystack isn't made of single letters but possibly strings of letters.

Comment: @STTLCU You're not OP though :)

Comment: @Jack - I see that works ... I will test it with some other values (as it may contain more than singles) :: Thank you :D

Comment: @theclueless1 I've updated my answer to include more than one character.

Comment: @Jack - Thank you again!  I'm printing out the resurlts of match - Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => a b c [1] => 4 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => a b c [1] => 24 ) ) ) ... I like seeing the searched for string (nice touch), but the numbers appear doubled?

Comment: @theclueless1 You have to use the `array_map()` I have in the answer.

Comment: @Jack - I must be doing something wrong ... as I've copied the code and I get : Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 5 [2] => 6 [3] => 7 [4] => 8 [5] => 9 [6] => 10 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 24 [1] => 25 [2] => 26 [3] => 27 [4] => 28 [5] => 29 [6] => 30 ) ) ?? What have I done wrong?