# Complex PHP Array search

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array structure with master data with thousands of records.

```
Array
   (
        [0] => 0,1
        [1] => 0,0
        [2] => 0,2
        [3] => 0,3
        [4] => 10,2
    )
```

I have a second array with a smaller subset. Such as

```
Array
   (
        [0] => 0,1
        [1] => 0,0
    )
```

I would like to find second array in first array in the extact same order of elements present in second array. But rather than doing an intersect I would like to find the key (or keys) from first array as well. I have been wrecking my brain on this...

UPDATED:

The keys are unique . So far example in above array I would like to see output of:

Array2 found in array1 (starting at key 0).

Second Example:

```
  Array
   (
        [a] => 0,1
        [b] => 0,0
        [c] => 0,2
        [d] => 0,3
        [e] => 10,2
    )
```

second array

```
Array
   (
         [1] => 0,3
         [2] => 10,2

    )
```

expected output:

second array match in array A, starting at key d of array A..

hope that clears it.

Comment: I'm assuming these arrays contain strings, e.g. "0,1" and that you've used `print_r()` to show it here? Are the array values unique? If so, you can `array_flip` the first array and loop for each value in `b` (*O(n)*) and look it up in `a` (*O(1)*). Also, perhaps [array_intersect_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php) and [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) might help you.

Comment: Show example of desired output given your two arrays.  And if you can, answer the question - that `0,1` is actually a string, `"0,1"`....

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect the exact ask.

Comment: In that case it's just an array_intersect. https://3v4l.org/gIb10

Comment: @andreas array_intersect also matches other elemets from first array that are not in order. For example if I set value of key b to "10,2" then output is "3 elements matched"... That is not what I want. I want to match extactly same amount of element as array B and in same order.

Comment: Define order then. In an associative array you can have the keys in whatever order you like.

Comment: @Andreas "define an order".... I have already above? What am I missing?

Comment: is `[A => 1, B => 2, C =>3]` the same as `[B =>2, C => 3, A => 1]`. They are the same only difference is the sort order.

Comment: @Andreas sorry to be pain. Can you please tell me through pesudocode or php code what you mean? or asking me to do?

Comment: Will the example I posted in my previous comment be all match or only B,C?

Comment: @Andreas ah ok..But as per my initial question the keys in both arrays are different and hence the ask :)

Comment: @Tommys, I give up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the solutions posted above work. What helped me is to re-structure my array and answer from here: [Find array in array, in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943607/find-array-in-array-in-sequence)

Comment: That is because you did not explain what you needed or answered the questions asked. That is why I wrote the comment *I give up*.

Comment: @andreas every easy to say that if you can't answer the question. You gave up because you couldn't do it. Simple.

Comment: I could tell you to go somewhere but choose not to. But you are wrong, simple as that

Comment: @Andreas this is not your personal therapy forum. This is for asking questions and getting answers. If you need someone's shoulder to cry on, this is not the place. You couldn't answer a question that is not the end of the world. You need to chill and stop whining like a little kid. Of you go now.

Comment: I just want to make sure anyone who sees this understand that it's not a matter of you are the only one who could solve it. You did not answer the questions we asked you and that meant everyone just left you. If you answer the questions people ask, you generally get at least one correct answer. But by not answering any of the questions below the question people gave up. That is the reality.

Comment: @Andreas the reality is you couldn't solve it...whatever makes you sleep at night buddy. I tried clarifying and got a response "I give up". So you couldn't be arsed to answer further. Sometimes the question does need more clarification then in that case ASK the right question not simply respond with "i give up".    There are plenty of questions all over SF which are not solved, it doesn't mean the question is not asked properly. you lose...go home.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is wrong with array_intersect.
As you describe your expected output it seems as array_intersect is perfect.

```
$a = Array
(
    15 => "0,1",
    16 => "0,0",
    2 => "0,2",
    3 => "0,3",
    4 => "10,2"
);

$b = Array
(
    0 => "0,1",
    1 => "0,0"
);

Var_dump(array_intersect($a, $b));
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [15]=>  string(3) "0,1"
  [16]=>  string(3) "0,0"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/KG1v6

Or if MonkeyZeus is correct maybe this can work for you?
I match array_intersect, then make sure the keys is the same.

```
$intersect = array_intersect($a, $b);
$keys = array_keys($intersect);

If($keys == array_keys($b)){
    Echo "they match";
}else{
    Echo "don't match";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/iiNmd

After OPs edit it seems it is a simple array_intersect that is needed.

https://3v4l.org/gIb10

```
$intersect =  array_intersect($a, $b);
Var_dump($intersect);
Echo "matching keys is: " . Implode(", ", array_keys($intersect));
```

Comment: I believe the issue is that OP wants to check if the sequence of items in array2 exist in array1. So from your `$a`, pretend that key #16 was actually after key #4 so the comparison should fail in that situation.

Comment: So you mean it has to be both values and keys that match?

Comment: OP mentions `exact same order of elements` so I assume that keys are irrelevant in the comparison but the returned result should be `$a` with keys intact so something like `array_sequence_intersect()` would be an appropriate fictional function name.

Comment: Never heard of array sequence intersect. Can't even find anything on Google about it.

Comment: You're right, it does not exist. I said that it would be an appropriate **"fictional**  function name". So if you were to make a custom function then `array_sequence_intersect()` would be a good name for it.

Comment: Ah! Sorry didn't catch it. I'm watching TV at the same time as typing here

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to get matching keys is

```
$result_array = array_intersect_assoc($array1, $array2);
$result_array_keys = array_keys(array_intersect_assoc($array1, $array2));
print_r($result_array);
print_r($result_array_keys); // this gives matching keys array
```